# Converting IQueryable<T> object to another object?

Tags: c#, .net

I have no idea what the keywords are so here is an example of what I want:

```
return from i in userRepo.GetUsers()
  select new SimpleUser{
        i.UserId,
        i.Name
  };
```

`userRepo.GetUsers()` returns type `IQueryable<User>`. I'd like to convert this to `IQueryable<SimpleUser>` to I can restrict access to certain properties of the `User` domain.

How do I do this without hard coding the translation like this? What about tools like automapper or ValueInjecter, how can they do this?

Also, what is this technique called?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must hardcode the translation or you must first convert it to `IEnumerable`. `IQueryable` represents expression tree translated to some execution in used provider - in your case I believe it will be Entity framework. You can't use any automatic mapping in such query because it will be translated to SQL which will not understand your .net methods or AutoMapper. Projections to custom types are part of the query and must be hardcoded. You can create custom extension method to `IQueryable` and reuse it where you need:

```
public static IQueryable<SimpleUser> ProjectToSimpleUser(this IQueryable<User> query)
{
    return query.Select(u => new SimpleUser
        {
            // Here map your fields
        });
}
```

Now you can use:

```
return repo.GetUsers().ProjectToSimpleUser();
```

In case of Entity framework `SimpleUser` mustn't be an mapped entity.

Comment: The code "u => u new SimpleUser" doesn't compile. I think that second "u" needs to be removed.

Answer (score 7):

Provided that SimpleUser is assigneable to User (User is an interface of baseclass of SimpleUser), you can

```
 var users = simpleUsers.Cast<User>();
```

optionally with

```
 var users = simpleUsers.Cast<User>().AsQueryable();
```

And if you're not sure whether all items are actually Users, then you can use `OfType<User>` instead of `Cast<User>`

Answer (score 3):

AutoMapper is the tool you want; it works via reflection and unless you tell it to do otherwise, it will map properties with the same name directly.

Auto-mapping is the technique.

Answer (score 1):

This question is 9 years old so idk if it existed then but for anyone searching now, using .FirstOrDefault() works if you pick a single user.