# Inline function call in Queryable Select

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I need some help working with an IQueryable collection of data items and then selecting them into a new form.

The following method is called to get some data from a repository:

```
var data = this.repository.GetAllPersonalDetails();
```

I want to then convert each item in the collection to a business object which I do using the following:

```
var businessTypes = data.Select(dataType => new PersonalDetails
    {
        FirstName = dataType.FirstName
        ...etc.
    });
```

This works fine and all is well, but the business object is quite big and I would like to make use of an adapter function that maps a data object to a business object. However, if I use code similar to the following:

```
var businessTypes = data.Select(dataType => this.ConvertToBusinessObject(dataType));
```

Then the whole Queryable pipeline gets messed up and I get exceptions when the query is eventually executed.

Does anyone know if what I'm trying to do is possible? It would be great if it was as we use adapter functions to convert between objects in a number of places and I'd rather re-use them instead of having to do the full conversion inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, the guidance given in the answer to this question worked perfectly for me.

[Converting IQueryable<T> object to another object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523792/converting-iqueryablet-object-to-another-object)

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, there has to be defined mapping from repository objects to business objects somewhere. You can't get it working without this or using LINQ select as you do.

There are many different ORMs (object-relational mappers) that maps database objects to business objects, but even they have to generate some adapters. For instace, Entity Framework uses templates to generate mapping classes and hides them under a context type so you are not bothered with it.

If you don't want or can't use any existing mapper, you can write your own adapters. When you are talking about adapters, I assume that you already know how they could be done.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ondrej. The repository mentioned in the above snippet is implemented using the LLBLGen ORM tool which works well so far. The conversion is between the LLBLGen entity type to our own Busines entity type. We can't switch to EF but I might look up the context types you mention. Cheers.

Comment: @Apogee Sorry to inform you that there is not easy way around. Hope that my answer made your thinking about the problem more clear.

Comment: I ended up following the guidance give in this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523792/converting-iqueryablet-object-to-another-object - thanks for the assistance though.

Answer (score -1):

[AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) is what you are looking for.

AutoMapper is a simple little library built to solve a deceptively complex problem - getting rid of code that mapped one object to another.

Comment: Sounds like an advertising to me. Consider providing short code snippet instead of this cheap description.

Comment: This is not advertising; All Open Source projects are there for using and learning.

Comment: Sure, but how this lousy description helps more than the provided link? The rule of thumb here on SO is that your answer should not only  consist from a link to a helpful website, but should also contain short code snippet using that tool, because some website simply die after some time, but code snippets here on SO don't.

Comment: So take the shortest one that is also relevant and post it in your answer instead that non-saying description.